# get all implementations of an api

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, bundles

I have written an API Bundle and some implementing services.

Now i want to use them as plugins, so first of all i need a list of all the services i have.

I'm starting the api like this:

```
    Framework m_fwk = new org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkFactory().newFramework(null);
    m_fwk.init();
    AutoProcessor.process(null, m_fwk.getBundleContext());
    m_fwk.start();

    Bundle api = m_fwk.getBundleContext().installBundle(
    "file:/foo/bar/api/target/api-1.0.jar");

    api.start();
```

So now the API is loaded. Now i need to know which bundles implements this API, how can i get this information from the framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only seem to load an API bundle, I guess you want to install other bundles for the implementations? Most people then load a director or so:

```
for ( File b : bundles.listFiles() ) {
    ctx.installBundle( b.toURI().toURL() );
}
```

Each of these bundle should look like (using DS):

```
@Component
public class Impl implements API {
  public whatever() { ... }
}
```

The bundle collecting the services could look like:

```
@Component
public class Collector {
  @Reference(type='*')
  void addAPI( API api ) { ... }
  void removeAPI( API api ) { ... }
}
```

This is done with the bnd annotations for DS (see bndtools for examples). However, you can also implement/collect the services in Blueprint, iPojo, and many other helpers.

Comment: mh yes, i want to have an API, which i need to install explicit. Then i want grab all bundles from a directory and look for these bundles which implements the API. For example: I have a Plugin-API and lots of plugins. now i want to load all plugins that match the API Version i installed previously. I think your example will do this right?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to re-implement the OSGi service registry. Have a look at Blueprint or Declarative Services instead. At the very least I'd suggest using the OSGi service API to register and consume services.

Answer (score 1):

Given that a [Framework](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/org/osgi/framework/launch/Framework.html) is also a `Bundle`, you can get a `BundleContext` that allows you to find all services you need. You could do something like

```
m_fwk.getBundleContext().getServiceReferences("com.example.MyInterface", null)
```

to get all implementers of a given service.

However, you should be aware that you are living in a different classloader than the inhabitants of your framework are.

Comment: Well, you need to be aware that the inhabitants of the framework have a different view of your interface than you have. If you just want all implementers, without worrying about assignability, use `getAllServiceReferences`. (If this assignability-stuff dazzles you, you can read up on OSGi class handling.)